# Threading Error: NameError: name 'datelabelstringvar' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

In python, I want a function to run at the same time as my normal script. I searched the internet and found threading, however, when I implement it and run the code, the error `NameError: name 'datelabelstringvar' is not defined` appears. I don't know what is wrong but when I remove threading and assign the function to a button (which I don't want just to be clear, I want it to be automatic), it works fine.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from numerize import numerize
import pygame
import os
import random
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import time

wholedate = datetime.date(datetime.now())
date = wholedate.strftime("%d")
month = wholedate.strftime("%m")
year = wholedate.strftime("%Y")

def advancetime():
    global date
    global month
    global year
    threading.Timer(5.0, advancetime).start()
    if month == "09" or month == "04" or month == "06" or month == "11":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 30:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
        return
    if month == "01" or month == "03" or month == "05" or month == "07" or month == "08" or month == "10" or month == "12":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 31:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
        return
    if month == "02":
        date = int(date) + 1
        if date > 31:
            date = 1
            month = int(month) + 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                year = int(year) + 1
        fixdate()
        fixmonth()
        datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))

def calendarOnClose():
    root.deiconify()
    calendarwindow.destroy()

def calendar():
    global datelabelstringvar
    global calendarwindow
    root.withdraw()
    calendarwindow = Toplevel()
    calendarwindow.title("Calendar")
    calendarwindow.geometry("400x350+300+100")
    calendarwindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", calendarOnClose)
    datelabelstringvar = StringVar()
    datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
    datelabel = Label(calendarwindow, textvariable=datelabelstringvar).grid(row="0", column="0")
    Button(calendarwindow, text="Advance Time", command=advancetime).grid(row="1", column="0")
    totalfruitclickerstringvar = StringVar()
    totalfruitclickerstringvar.set("Fruit Clicked: " + str(totalfruitclicked))
    Label(calendarwindow, textvariable=totalfruitclickerstringvar).grid(row="2", column="0")

root = Tk()
root.title("Fruit Clicker")
root.geometry("400x350+300+100")

calendarbutton = Button(root, text="Calendar", fg="White", bg="Black", width="11", command=calendar)
calendarbutton.grid(row="8", column="0")

advancetime()

root.mainloop()
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks.

EDIT:
Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\colli\Documents\GitHub\FruitClicker\windows\main.py", line 1708, in <module>
    advancetime()
  File "C:\Users\colli\Documents\GitHub\FruitClicker\windows\main.py", line 113, in advancetime
    datelabelstringvar.set(str(date) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year))
NameError: name 'datelabelstringvar' is not defined
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I just edited it, is this ok?

Comment: There is still lots of unnecessary code. For example, are all of those “if” statements really necessary _this question_?

Comment: You should not call `advancetime()` before `root.mainloop()` because at that moment `calendar()` has not been called yet and so `datelabelstringvar` has not been created yet as well.

Comment: I tried this and ```advancetime()``` doesnt run

Comment: Then you need to call `calendar()` before `advancetime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes several references to a `datelabelstringvar` variable.  However, you never define it.  That's what Python is saying.

EDIT:

It doesn't appear that you ever call the `calendar` function where the variable is defined.

Comment: ```datelabelstringvar``` is defined in calendar

Comment: Then you need to import it.

Comment: how? I've globalized it, shouldn't that work? When I remove the threading, it works fine

Comment: Nope.  You need to tell Python that you want to use the `datelabelstringvar` variable from the `calendar` module.  So, `from calendar import datelabelstringvar`.

Comment: You also need to remove the `global datelabelstringvar` line.

Comment: So I've done what you said, now i get ```ImportError: cannot import name 'datelabelstringvar' from 'calendar' (C:\Users\colli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\calendar.py)```

Comment: Are you sure `datelabelstringvar` is in the `calendar` module?  I don't see it in the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html).

Comment: Calendar isn't a module, its a function.

Comment: Oh.  You meant your `calendar` function.  I thought you meant the `calendar` module.

Comment: So how do I fix the original ```NameError: name 'datelabelstringvar' is not defined``` error

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Comment: I don't understand, the ```datelabelstringvar``` variable is defined in ```calendar```, then its edited in ```advancetime``` all I want to do is make the function run automatically in the background. Can you give me a snippet of code as an example?

Comment: But you never call `calendar`.  How does the variable ever get defined if you never run the code which defines it?

Comment: Put a call to `calendar` right before the call to `advancetime`.

Comment: Like this: ```calendar() (new line) 
advancetime()```? same error

Comment: Which line specifically is giving you the error?  Can you edit your original post to display the traceback of the error?

Comment: Ok I did that. What now?

Comment: This may be a stupid question so, if so, I ask for your forgiveness, but did you save your file after adding the call to `calendar`?  If the `calendar` function is being run, then `datelabelstringvar` should be defined.  Try this, put a `print` statement at the first line of the `calendar` function (like `print('Running calendar')`).  Then put `print` statements before and after the line `datelabelstringvar = StringVar()`.  Save the file, re-run it, and tell me what the output was.

Comment: Ah. I fixed it. All I had to do was add ```global datelabelstringvar``` in ```calendar```. Thanks for the guidance with calling ```calendar``` before ```advancetime```

Comment: @JaydenCollis, if you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote it.